# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, android-studio, select, android-sqlite

Estoy a punto de volverme loco. Intento hacer una consulta a mi base de datos sqlite en mi app de android. Hasta donde puedo ver tengo todo bien pero me sale como si no consiguiera nada en la consulta.

Mi tabla contiene lo siguiente:

```
miDB.execSQL("create table if not exists quehaceres (titulo VARCHAR(50), imagen INT, fecha_inicio VARCHAR(10), fecha_final VARCHAR(10)," +
            "id_contenedor INT, id_titulo INT, id_editar INT, id_imagen INT, id_fechaInicial INT, id_fechaFinal INT)");
```

Mi consulta se hace al tocar un botón para editar, en este caso asigno el ID del botón a la variable id_edi1:

```
    if (v.getId() == id_edi1){

            cursor3 = miDB.rawQuery("select titulo, imagen, monto_inicial, monto_final, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, id_contenedor, id_titulo," +
                    "id_editar, id_imagen, id_montoInicial, id_montoFinal, id_fechaInicial, id_fechaFinal from objetivos where id_editar=" + id_edi1, null);

            layout_editar1 = findViewById(cursor3.getInt(6));
            titulo_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(0));

            montoFinal_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(3));
            montoInicial_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(2));
            fechaInicial_editar.setText(cursor3.getString(4));
            fechaLimite_editar.setText(cursor3.getString(5));
}
```

Cada vez que el usuario añade un elemento, este se añade a la base de datos con el siguiente método y pasándole los valores que quiero que guarde:

```
public void añadirFilaBD(String titulo_nuevo, int imagen_nuevo, String monto_inicial_nuevo, String monto_final_nuevo, String fecha_inicial_nuevo, String fecha_final_nuevo,
                         int id1, int id2, int id3, int id4, int id5, int id6, int id7, int id8){

    ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
    row.put("titulo", titulo_nuevo);
    row.put("imagen", imagen_nuevo);
    row.put("monto_inicial", monto_inicial_nuevo);
    row.put("monto_final", monto_final_nuevo);
    row.put("fecha_inicio", fecha_inicial_nuevo);
    row.put("fecha_final", fecha_final_nuevo);
    row.put("id_contenedor", id1); row.put("id_titulo", id2); row.put("id_editar", id3);
    row.put("id_imagen", id4); row.put("id_montoInicial", id5); row.put("id_montoFinal", id6);
    row.put("id_fechaInicial", id7); row.put("id_fechaFinal", id8);

    miDB.insert("objetivos", null, row);

}
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Comprobé que los valores estuvieran correctos, pero creo que el problema yace en el select, sino definitivamente estoy ciego o loco.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Considera migrar tu código a Room [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room?gclid=CjwKCAjwztL2BRATEiwAvnALcqSMW-iKJc6S9EKEXcfXlEt2aLXSWqLm-5uvvXcN_6SwkWZCHYhNNBoCO0cQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) Te da errores de compilación en tus querys y más control, respecto a tu problema lo más probable que tu consulta no te este regresando información, si quieren que alguien te ayude es importante publicar más información, como iteras el cursor, etc...

Comment: Gracias por responer @Ghost Voy a ver eso de Android Room. Por el momento añadiré más información a ver si puedo resolver el problema. Y sí, estás en lo correcto, es como si al consultar no viera el elemento que estoy pidiendo con el where, pero no entiendo el por qué.

Comment: Te lo recomiendo mucho, sobre todo si estas inciando el proyecto o estás capacitandote, Room te hace el mapeo de tus datos a una clase y ya solo accedes por medio de las propiedades, te evitas tener que hacer.. get(indice) y demás cosas que te pueden generar temas

Answer (score 0):

Verifica la consulta, esta no esta obteniendo datos.

Debes validar siempre al obtener un cursor con el resultado de una consulta, en este caso no se están obteniendo resultados y tratas de obtener el valor de un cursor, por esa razón obtienes el error:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 1

la forma de validar sería:

```
if (v.getId() == id_edi1){

        cursor3 = miDB.rawQuery("select titulo, imagen, monto_inicial, monto_final, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, id_contenedor, id_titulo," +
                "id_editar, id_imagen, id_montoInicial, id_montoFinal, id_fechaInicial, id_fechaFinal from objetivos where id_editar=" + id_edi1, null);

    //* Verifica datos en cursor.
    if(c.moveToFirst()){ 
        layout_editar1 = findViewById(cursor3.getInt(6));
        titulo_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(0));

        montoFinal_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(3));
        montoInicial_editar.getEditText().setText(cursor3.getString(2));
        fechaInicial_editar.setText(cursor3.getString(4));
        fechaLimite_editar.setText(cursor3.getString(5));
    }else{
      //NO hubo resultados al realizar la consulta.
    }

}
```